# Webpack file-loader not working for images. Creating curropted file and img src is pointed to that file

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I am using webpack file-loader to load images into an HTML page. It is generating a corrupted file and using src as that file, in img tag.

this is my setting in webpack.config.js

```
{
            test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg)$/,
            use:
            [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options:
                    {   
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'images/',
                        publicPath: 'images/'
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
```

final image tag which is generated

```
<img src="8c7b2da10ea507a829fd.jpg" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

file-loader is deprecated for webpack version 5 so switching to Asset Modules worked, here's the documentation.

[Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/)

Comment: Why not add the code to which you changed and that's now working as well?

Answer (score 0):

webpack version 5 works in diff way and does not require `file-loader` anymore

add that to your webpack configuration instead

```
{
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
    type: 'asset/resource',
    generator: {
       filename: 'images/[name][ext]'
    }
}
```